# How Can I display the number before section in bookmark?

Tags: numbering, bookmarks

I want to make a bookmark. I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{Some tex}
\section{Section two}
\subsection{Some tex}
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{Some tex}
\section{Section two}
\subsection{Some tex}
\end{document}
```

I got

[image]

I want to have the subsection has the form `1.1 Subection one`,...

How can I make bookmark like this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}  % I Changed this line
%\usepackage{bookmark}  % Not really necessary
\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{Some tex}
\section{Section two}
\subsection{Some tex}
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{Some tex}
\section{Section two}
\subsection{Some tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]